# How chaincode is install from local filesystem

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have written the chaincode its in local system, now i need to install chaincode in hyperledger fabric peers.How it is done from local system to install the chaincode to my peer node. below code is taken from hyperledger fabric chaincode example.please suggest me

```
 package main

 import (
"fmt"
"strconv"

"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
 pb "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
  )

   // SimpleChaincode example simple Chaincode implementation
   type SimpleChaincode struct {
   }

     func (t *SimpleChaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) 
      pb.Response {
fmt.Println("ex02 Init")
_, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
var A, B string    // Entities
var Aval, Bval int // Asset holdings
var err error

    if len(args) != 4 {
    return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 4")
 }

// Initialize the chaincode
A = args[0]
Aval, err = strconv.Atoi(args[1])
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("Expecting integer value for asset holding")
}
B = args[2]
Bval, err = strconv.Atoi(args[3])
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error("Expecting integer value for asset holding")
}
fmt.Printf("Aval = %d, Bval = %d\n", Aval, Bval)

// Write the state to the ledger
err = stub.PutState(A, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Aval)))
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error(err.Error())
}

err = stub.PutState(B, []byte(strconv.Itoa(Bval)))
if err != nil {
    return shim.Error(err.Error())
}

return shim.Success(nil)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the chaincode in several ways

- NodeSDK
- JavaSDK
- CLI

I would suggest you try with CLI first, fabric-samples has one example.

Behind the seen fabric compile and only binary file will be deployed to the peer

Comment: Thank you  for the replay, i was having trouble installing chaincode through cli, i figured it out